# Google maps slide up marker info window

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on a android app with google maps and I realize that in android Google maps app they replace [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows) with new more flexible design like this.
Is the new design similar or the same implementation with info window?
How to implement the same behavior like Google map app?

[**Example pictures**]

**Old design:**

[image: Info window]

**New design:**

[image: Mobile]
[image: Tablet]

**UPDATE:**

Finally I used Google's [bottomSheet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html)

Answer (score 2):

They are using a bottom sheet. Check out the google design guidelines:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html

Look at

**Persistent bottom sheets** present in-app content.

Here is some code on it:
https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

Comment: I am investigating also this [approach.](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)